# Is there anyway to disable a bootstrap button permanently after one click on server side using PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, html, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to disable a bootstrap button permanently after one click. I know how to do this on client side using JavaScript but after refreshing page, it becomes enabled. So, I want to do it on the server side. But don't know how to do it. Can anyone help??

Comment: you need to store somewhere in DB and based on that you can achieve that.

Comment: use ajax to store a value in DB like `clicked=1` and then check the condition whenever the page loads.

Comment: You could do it client side with [localStorage](https://blog.logrocket.com/the-complete-guide-to-using-localstorage-in-javascript-apps-ba44edb53a36) or cookies...

Comment: Maintain a session variable named "clicked =  true " using PHP or store the same in database. Everytime the page loads use "isset()" in case of PHP to check the value of session variable or use ajax calls in case of database to get the variable from the database.

Comment: Please include a code example of your button and what you have already attempted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There would need to be informed in a database in order for the button to know if it needs to be pressed.

I would suggest either using an Ajax request to do an insert statement into a database once the selected button is pressed or you can use it through a  tag submits into an insert statement in order to get the data to see if it should be permanently selected.

Then you would need a select statement to read the database data into an IF statement such as this;

```
($row['Button_Pressed'] == '1' ? 'Selected' : '')
```

The Button_Pressed is just the column in the table that would store the data and the 1 is the boolean value

Answer (score 0):

This solution worked for me to disable a bootstrap button:

```
<?php
    $a=1;
    echo ($a==1) ? '<a href="update.php" class="btn btn-success btn-lg">Mark complete</a>' : '<a href="lect_pro_updater.php" class="btn btn-success btn-lg disabled">You completed this</a>';
?>
```

It will keep button active if the condition is true else create a new disabled button.

If you don't want to use a ternary operator then use if and else statements like:

```
if($a==1){
'<a href="update.php" class="btn btn-success btn-lg">Mark complete</a>'
}

else{
'<a href="update.php" class="btn btn-success btn-lg disabled">Mark complete</a>'
}
```